# Take the touch listener of an view and call an touch event on another view

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, ontouchlistener, translate

I have a viewpager with this listener.

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            Float translation = position * viewpagerWidth *Constants.density;
            if(positionOffset != 0)
                image.setTranslationX(- translation -(positionOffsetPixels * Constants.density)/12);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            page = position;
            mButtons.updateViewIntro(position + 1);
            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    title.setText(getString(R.string.passenger_name));
                    subtitle.setText(getString(R.string.intro_passenger_subtitle));
                    new FadeOutAnimation(arrowleft).animate();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    title.setText(getString(R.string.intro_mileage));
                    subtitle.setText(getString(R.string.intro_mileage_subtitle));
                    if(arrowleft.getVisibility() == View.GONE || arrowleft.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                        new FadeInAnimation(arrowleft).animate();
                    if(arrowright.getVisibility() == View.GONE || arrowright.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE)
                        new FadeInAnimation(arrowright).animate();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    title.setText(getString(R.string.intro_analytics));
                    subtitle.setText(getString(R.string.intro_analytics_subtitle));
                    new FadeOutAnimation(arrowright).animate();
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```

My question is: If I have another view, at the bottom, that is in no way connected to this viewpager. is it possible to set an touch listener on it, and make it so that it will also call the onPageChangeListener of the viewpager?
As in, I want to be able to scrol the viewpager by pressing on another object. (I need to add it on the image too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simply set a touch listener to your view and then call setCurrentItem on the pager.

```
private final View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(<page number here>);
    }
}
```

Edit: based on your comment, try this:

```
yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mPager.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: not what I need.
An example: You know when you DO NOT change the viewpager page, but you just scroll the viewpager like for example to half. and you get in the listener the ScrollOffset in pixels, etc...
I want to touch another view, which is below, and in the touch event of that view, it passes it tot he viewpager, so that the onPageChanged listener is called, and I get the ScrollOffset in pixels from it. Basically , if I swipe on the view from the  bottom, I see how the viewpager is moving...

Comment: I don't understand why you would want to do that, seems unintuitive to scroll a view by dragging your finger over a separate view (how is the user supposed to learn that?). However, you can achieve it by defining a touch listener for your view, and then calling mPager.onTouch(event) with the event from your view.

Comment: Thanks. will try now. Well. I have a viewpager in the middle of the page. and I have a background, which is bigger than the screen, and it's a imageview that I translate through, creating an parallax effect. This works when I scroll the viewpager. BUT, my boss wants it to work also when I press the background parallax image.... so yeah.